# Is there a utility that interprets /proc/interrupts data over time?

Tags: linux, proc, interrupt

Is there something out there? Like **top** is for **ps**

Comment: Usually, it is better to add your answer as an actual answer rather than editing the question.

Answer (score 13):

```
watch -n0.1 --no-title cat /proc/interrupts
```

Comment: This is very hard to use if you have many threads, it wraps the screen.

Answer (score 11):

`dstat` can also be used for that.

```
dstat -tif 60
```

To list all the interrupts (those with more than 10 in `/proc/stat`)

```
dstat -tf --int24 60
```

Same but using `/proc/interrupts`, so include things like `LOC`, `PMI`, `RES`...

You can also select the list of those you want:

```
$ dstat -t --int24 -I23,LOC,RES 5
----system---- ----interrupts---
     time     |  23   LOC   RES
21-12 16:30:23|   2   489    52
21-12 16:30:28|  30   593     6
21-12 16:30:30|  37   929     7
```

See also `--top-int` to track the most active interrupt:

```
$ dstat -t --top-int
----system---- ---most-frequent----
     time     |     interrupt
21-12 16:33:21|5242880-edge enp10s0  56
21-12 16:33:22|5242880-edge enp10s0  68
21-12 16:33:23|5242880-edge enp10s0   4
21-12 16:33:24|5242880-edge enp10s0   3
21-12 16:33:25|5242880-edge enp10s0  61
21-12 16:33:26|5242880-edge enp10s0  11
21-12 16:33:27|512000-edge ahci[0000:00:1f.2]   5
21-12 16:33:28|5242880-edge enp10s0  52
21-12 16:33:29|5242880-edge enp10s0  20
21-12 16:33:30|32768-edge i915  57
```

Answer (score 4):

`mpstat(1) N M -I` lets you do this with a specified polling interval and number of reports.

- `N` is the polling interval, in seconds.
- `M` is the number of times to report.
- According to [the man page](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mpstat1.html), `-I`, which takes a number of options, is to "Report interrupts statistics".

Furthermore,

> intr/s
>   Show the total number of interrupts received per second by the CPU or CPUs.
>   With  the  CPU keyword, the number of each individual interrupt received per second by the CPU or CPUs is displayed. **Interrupts are those listed in /proc/interrupts file.**

Answer (score 4):

For a server with lot's of CPUs, I found https://github.com/lanceshelton/irqstat very useful. It shows where interrupts are happening in real time:

```
Sun Oct 21 20:16:09 2018
IRQs / 5 second(s)
IRQ#  TOTAL  NODE0   NODE1  NAME
  35  38060  38060       0  IR-PCI-MSI 2621440-edge enp5s0-rx-0
  36  19853  19853       0  IR-PCI-MSI 2621441-edge enp5s0-tx-0
  34    311    311       0  IR-PCI-MSI 512000-edge ahci[0000:00:1f.2]
  29    105    105       0  IR-PCI-MSI 2097152-edge enp4s0-rx-0
  42      0      0       0  IR-PCI-MSI 77824-edge ioat-msix
  43      0      0       0  IR-PCI-MSI 79872-edge ioat-msix
  49      0      0       0  IR-PCI-MSI 67180544-edge ioat-msix
  52      0      0       0  IR-PCI-MSI 67186688-edge ioat-msix
  53      0      0       0  IR-PCI-MSI 67188736-edge ioat-msix
  48      0      0       0  IR-PCI-MSI 67178496-edge ioat-msix
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is [irqtop](https://manpath.be/f33/1/irqtop) which is part of not too old [util-linux](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) releases. For example, Fedora 33 is the first Fedora release that has it.

In the latest util-linux release, irqtop is also able to display softirqs (cf. `--softirq`).

Example:

```
$ irqtop -s delta
irqtop | total: 182243195 delta: 163991 | example.org | 2021-05-09 23:39:32+02:00

IRQ    TOTAL DELTA NAME
 63 14890381 35488 IR-PCI-MSI 3145728-edge eno3-TxRx-0
 64 14661318 34614 IR-PCI-MSI 3145729-edge eno3-TxRx-1
 58 29720656 23291 IR-PCI-MSI 2623488-edge eno2-TxRx-0
 61 29676645 23268 IR-PCI-MSI 2623491-edge eno2-TxRx-3
 60 29676091 23266 IR-PCI-MSI 2623490-edge eno2-TxRx-2
 59 29686036 23259 IR-PCI-MSI 2623489-edge eno2-TxRx-1
LOC  5524971   755 Local timer interrupts
 52    39316    14 IR-PCI-MSI 2621443-edge eno1-TxRx-3
CAL 12209964    12 Function call interrupts
 50    38809     6 IR-PCI-MSI 2621441-edge eno1-TxRx-1
 49    45351     4 IR-PCI-MSI 2621440-edge eno1-TxRx-0
 51    39170     2 IR-PCI-MSI 2621442-edge eno1-TxRx-2
```

Comment: Could not get this to work properly. There is a nasty unstable bug with ruby-curses that shoots a bunch of warnings all over the screen. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=958973 I am going to admit I could try to spend time fixing this but that involves setting up ruby / gem / other supported packages and env. Rather find a solution that is native to most linux systems.

Comment: @Dave You are trying to use the wrong `irqtop`! For comparison, on a Fedora 35 system: `rpm -qf $(which irqtop)` -> `util-linux-2.37.4-1.fc35.x86_64` and `file $(which irqtop)` -> `/usr/bin/irqtop: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable [..]` IOW, try the `irqtopq` that is part of the util-linux package!

Answer (score 0):

a bash quickie

```
A=/tmp/_1 ; B=/tmp/_2 ; 
while true ; do \
    cat /proc/interrupts > $A ; \
        diff -y $A $B | \
        head -n $((LINES-1)) | \
        sed "s|\(.*\)..[0-9A-Z]:.*|\1|" | \
        grep -C 99 --color "^.*|" ; \
    C=$A ; A=$B ; B=$C ;\
    sleep 1 ;\
done
```

explanation: with two temporary files, save the contents of /proc/interrupts to the first, show the differences between it the other (limited to 1 less than number of lines on the screen, and highlit with grep's coloring), switch the tmpfiles around, sleep a second, and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I am submitting my answer that does the following:

- Uses native linux commands (`cat`, `sed`, `grep` , `watch`)
- Does require installing `rs` (perform a `sudo apt install rs` before running the command below)
- Supports many cpu nodes (this was the most important requirement)
- Mainly used to `grep` what you want to display. In my case I needed only to see my network cards info:

Mainly I wanted to make all columns rows when performing a simple `cat /proc/interrupts`

```
watch -n1 -d "cat /proc/interrupts | grep 'CPU\|enp94s0f2v1' | sed -e '1 s/^/Irq_num /' | sed -e '1 s/$/Type Type_detail Thread/'  | sed 's/  */ /g' | sed 's/^ //g' | rs -c' ' -C' ' -T | column -t"
```

This will output and update with watch like the following:

```
Irq_num      457:                     458:                     459:                     460:
CPU0         2                        0                        0                        0
CPU1         0                        2                        0                        0
CPU2         0                        0                        2                        0
CPU3         0                        0                        0                        1
CPU4         221961382                0                        0                        0
CPU5         0                        0                        0                        0
CPU6         0                        212112424                0                        0
CPU7         0                        0                        0                        0
CPU8         0                        0                        0                        0
CPU9         0                        0                        0                        0
CPU10        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU11        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU12        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU13        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU14        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU15        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU16        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU17        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU18        0                        0                        0                        1244
CPU19        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU20        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU21        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU22        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU23        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU24        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU25        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU26        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU27        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU28        0                        0                        1170                     0
CPU29        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU30        0                        0                        0                        0
CPU31        0                        0                        0                        0
Type         IR-PCI-MSI               IR-PCI-MSI               IR-PCI-MSI               IR-PCI-MSI
Type_detail  49448961-edge            49448962-edge            49448963-edge            49448964-edge
Thread       iavf-enp94s0f2v1-TxRx-0  iavf-enp94s0f2v1-TxRx-1  iavf-enp94s0f2v1-TxRx-2  iavf-enp94s0f2v1-TxRx-3
```

Answer (score 0):

The newly developed utility [`pw` ("Pipe Watch")](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/pw/about/) can monitor anything that produces voluminous output, with useful interactive features such as triggering, filtering, split panes and more.

[This video](https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/710155314) demonstrates `pw` being fed a continuous stream produced by `cat /proc/interrupts` in a shell `while` loop.

`pw` is about 2000 lines of code, in one file, with no dependencies other than POSIX C library functions. It has a detailed man page.